# IOS Phonegap 3.X: Lock page orientation during runtime

Tags: ios, cordova, rotation, orientation

I am developing a webapp using phonegap + sencha touch, and I want to lock orientation on certain pages during runtime. I found [this phonegap plugin](https://github.com/acti0nm4n/Phonegap-Orientation-iOS)  , but it's not working for phonegap 3.X.

I also found something about a js function which named 'shouldRotateToOrientation', is it provided by phonegap? And it seems just works in multi-page(html files) app, my sencha touch app only have one html file.

So, how can I do that? Any help from you will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a phonegap plugin for android/ios.
https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation

Answer (score 1):

i know this is not really a valid "answer" but SO doesn't let me comment with <50 rep. anyway, i noticed it's not that difficult to set up an old plugin to be used with cordova 3+. adhere to the folder structure (which you can see in existing cordova plugins like "device"), create a plugin.xml and install the plugin with plugman. read the documentation about plugin development and you should be good.

you will especially have to replace the function header in the ios files. replace

```
-(void)setAllowed:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
```

with

```
- (void)setAllowed:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
```

Comment: can you be more specific please? Struggling with installation and will I still have to change Appdelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files? Thank you